# String.split vs StringUtils.split in Java gives different results

Tags: java, string, split, apache-stringutils

Consider a string like below with delimiter `__|__`.

```
String str = "a_b__|__c_d";
```

`str.split("__\\|__")` gives 2 splits a_b and c_d
`StringUtils.split(str, "__|__") or StringUtils.split(str, "__\\|__")` gives 4 splits a, b, c, d which is not desired.

Is there any way to make StringUtils.split() to give same results String.split()?

Comment: Use StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator instead!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String.split()` has some [very surprising](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#splitter) semantics, and it's rarely what you want. You should prefer `StringUtils` (or Guava's [`Splitter`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html), discussed in the previous link).

Your specific issue is that `String.split()` takes a regular expression, while [`StringUtils.split()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) uses each character as a separate token. You should use [`StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#splitByWholeSeparator-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to split on the contents of the full string.

```
StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator(str, "__|__");
```

Comment: I recommend StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens("-a--b-", "-") -> ["", "a", "", "b", ""] which matches PHP's explode("-", "-a--b-") -> ["", "a", "", "b", ""]. StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator("-a--b-", "-") returns ["a", "b", ""] which I find unexpected.

Comment: Matching PHP semantics is, generally speaking, probably an anti-goal ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, as per documentation, second parameter of StringUtils.split is the list of all characters that are considered splitters.
There is a different function in Apache Commons which does what you want - StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator. Still, I don't get what's wrong with simple String.split.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize such method exists. Well I can use String.split() but I prefer StringUtils. splitByWholeSeparator() as it takes of null strings also.